# Trouble with horizontal viewing when centering background image using css

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a simple page which should always have its background image centered horizontally.

Here is my css:

```
body {
    background-image: url(htts://url_to_my_image.png);
    background-position: top center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

and my **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Latency/tvPna/):**

The problem occurs when the browser window isn't tall enough to fit the entire image. I seem to be unable to scroll to the bottom of the page (thus cannot view the bottom of the image). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`background-size: 100% 100%;` may help you

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tvPna/2/)**

**ADDED CSS ::**

```
html,body{
background-size:100% 100%;
min-height:100%;
}
```

and if you want a scroll bar to view the full image then dont use that image using `background` but display it using `<img src="" />`

**OR..**

if you still want to have a scroll bar to show the full image while it is set as `backround` then set the `min-height` of your container (in your case `html,body`) equals to the actual height of the image

**[MAKING BACKGROUND IMAGE SCROLL](http://jsfiddle.net/tvPna/4/)**

Comment: This will be your best bet, it's a background image, the page will not resize to fit the background image. Your other option is to have it as an image itself, rather than a background image. Read more about the background-size property [here](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/) Also try `background-size:contain`